# Add WCF Service option not available in VisualStudio 2017

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2017

I am new to WCF and trying to add my own service to the project. But when I am right-clicking the project options to add WCF Service, that option which should come is not available. [image]

How can I add WCF Service to the project which is the .svc file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Add New Item there I got the option it has been changed in VisualStudio 2017
[image]

Comment: Do you have any questions now?